# Get information of Tabs open in TabNavigator in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

[alt text http://img195.imageshack.us/img195/7845/tabx.jpg](http://img195.imageshack.us/img195/7845/tabx.jpg)

i am opening tabs with click event on tree list view.

Problem is that i do not want open tab Pista as u can see in image again.

i want to focus that open Pista tab.

Pls give ur suggestions.

Thanks.

Regards,

Shivang

Comment: Can you explain what you're looking for exactly? ... Is it that you want the tab to have focus - but not 'select'... meaning the previous tab would still be selected - but 'focus' would be on the new tab?

Comment: How come I don't see pasta in the tree, or even four nodes for that matter? Is there a mapping from the tree to the tabs? What does your code look like?

Comment: Hi Guys,
sorry for late reply, busy with other project.
Here i took label of tabs from the tree xml data.
U can see in image that Pista tab opened two times. If user click on Pista in tree, if it is already open in tab then focus that tab. Not open new tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a function that loops through the tabs to see if the tab already exists and if it does set the tabNavigators selectedIndex, if it doesnt add the new tab

```
var tabFound:Boolean = false;
for(var i:int = 0; i < myTabNavigator.numChildren; i++)
{
    if(myTabNavigator.getChildAt(i) is myNewObj)
    {
       myTabNavigator.selectedIndex = i;
       tabFound = true;
       break;
    }
}
if(!tabFound)
{
    myTabNavigator.addChild(myNewObj);
}
```

I quickly wrote that code up and didnt test it, but the logic would be similar.